# IF statements to display results from checkboxes using a message box in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and have created a userform which allows a user to select which subjects they would like to take for semester 1 and semester 2 of a the school year, using multiple checkboxes. Once the user has selected their options, the message box displays a summary of what they have picked. Currently my code works but only shows the first picked option for each semester, what do I need to change in the below code so all the options that they pick are shown? From below screenshot you can see my form, and as you can see the messagebox is only showing the first option from each list. Many thanks!

### [image: Screenshot]

'Confirm options

```
If Me.IB1.Value = True Then
msg1 = ("International Business 1" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.BP1.Value = True Then
msg1 = msg1 + ("Business Programming 1" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.BP.Value = True Then
msg1 = msg1 + ("Business Planning" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.LI.Value = True Then
msg1 = msg1 + ("Leading & Influencing" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.MS.Value = True Then
msg1 = msg1 + ("Management Science" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.CS.Value = True Then
msg2 = ("Corporate Strategy" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.PM.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("Project Management" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.BE.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("Business Ethics" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.BF.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("Business Finance" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.IB2.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("International Business 2" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.BP2.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("Business Programming 2" & Chr(13))
End If

If Me.CG.Value = True Then
msg2 = msg2 + ("Corporate Governance" & Chr(13))
End If

MsgBox ("You have chosen the following options for semester 1" & Chr(13) & msg1 & _
"You have chosen the following options for semester 2" & Chr(13) & msg2)
End If
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you're attempting to delete this because it is classwork, [please read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions)

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit because it rendered the code invalid. The effort to make the code shorter would be welcome per se, but you need to take care to not introduce errors, and also make sure it doesn't make the answer harder to understand (which will often be the case when the answer was in response to an earlier version of the code).

Comment: ... Actually, looks like somebody else was faster (-:

Comment: I'm simply trying to remove the screenshot, the actual code can remain. I can't see an issue with doing so when the code is still there and still helpful to others. Thank you

Comment: @SarahL500 The image seems to be an integral part of the question to go with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
Private Sub btnConfirm_Click()
Dim strResult As String

    strResult = ""
    If Me.IB.Value = True Then
        strResult = strResult & Me.IB.Caption
    End If

    If Me.BP.Value = True Then
        strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & Me.BP.Caption
    End If

    If Me.BP1.Value = True Then
        strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & Me.BP1.Caption
    End If

    If Me.LI.Value = True Then
        strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & Me.LI.Caption
    End If

    MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```

> Edit

If you want to iterate all checkboxes in a userform then try following

```
Private Sub btnShowSelected_Click()
Dim strResult As String

strResult = "You have selected following checkboxes." & vbCrLf
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & ctrl.Caption
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl

MsgBox strResult
End Sub
```

[image]